# Trouble installing Windows software using WINE

Tags: wine

I am trying to install the Bet365 poker client using Wine but I keep running into a problem.  After I run the installer it process seems to hang for a few minutes with no progress and then I get an error message on screen saying

> Please check your internet connection and try to run the installer again

This is the latest client downloaded from the Bet365 website.  It runs fine from my Windows 10 laptop but the kids have taken over that device for their Minecraft needs.

New to Wine and currently learning Ubuntu.

How can I get it working?

Comment: The best way is forget about WINE, and install Windows into VirtualBox, and then Bet365 as a standard Windows install.

Comment: What version of wine are you using?

Comment: @FCTW I am using wine-1.6.2. This happens across several distros too on different machines.

Comment: @heynnema I have ended up doing that it works a treat

Comment: @DaveRace your comment wasn't quite clear. Did you install Virtualbox, and if so, is it working for you? Do you want me to make that into an answer so that you can vote/accept my answer?

Comment: @heynnema Yes i installed virtual box and a copy of Windows 7.  I am now running the Bet365 through that.  Yes pleasemake it into an answer.

Comment: @DaveRace  Done! I'm glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, WINE isn't a very good substitute for a real Windows environment, whether it's running on its own metal, or running in a virtual environment like Virtualbox.

The best way is forget about WINE, and install a Windows guest OS in VirtualBox, and then Bet365 as a standard Windows install.