# LINE error when it updates

Tags: wine

So I don't know what just happened.
I need help with this because I'm new to Ubuntu.
It worked before the update comes in
[image: This is what the error looks like]

I've tried to reinstall it multiple times but yet it gives same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing Windows software using WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910834/trouble-installing-windows-software-using-wine)

Comment: @melebius before the update comes, my Line works fine tho

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not prove that the update or any other version will work…